# Footer/Header for CHTCollectionViewWaterfallFlowLayout?

Tags: uicollectionview

With CHTCollectionViewWaterfallFlowLayout implemented, my viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind and referenceSizeForFooterInSection are not called.

This only happens with collectionViews that use CHTCollectionViewWaterfallFlowLayout.  The library readme states that it supports header and footer, but not seem to be the case? Or am I missing something here?

https://github.com/chiahsien/CHTCollectionViewWaterfallLayout

I've tried opening an issue but haven't seen anything.

Thanks!